# AVRO need to set a value for each field

Tags: avro

I have an AVRO schema with a bunch of elements.  In each element I provide a default value.  But when I attempt to serialize I get an exception if I attempt to not set any element with a value.  Even if I just provide an empty string for an element then I don't get these serialization exceptions.

Comment: If the field is not nullable, then it is required... But can you share the schema?

Comment: Also, defaults are only used when *reading fields*, not set in the record when written/produced... https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#schema_complex

Answer (score 0):

The "default" field at avro schema is used for schema evolution cases. See http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution for its rules.

The default value is not used when serializing (writing) the data. It is used when desalinizing (reading) avro data, which was produced with schema which lack the field.

e.g. if we have data which was produced with this schema:

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"Product",
    "fields":[
         {"name":"product_id","type": "long"}
    ]
 }
```

and we want to read it (resolve it) using extended schema which contains also product_name field like this:

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"Product",
    "fields":[
        {"name":"product_id","type": "long"},
        {"name":"product_name","type": "string","default":"old product data"},
    ]
}
```

The default value will be used to set a value for the field 'product_name' which is missing from the data, as the data was written using the first schema.